# chartjs-plugin-error-bars display error-bars without displaying label on a horizontalBar chart

Tags: chart.js, errorbar

i am trying to add error bars to a horizontal bar chart in chartjs using the chartjs-plugin-error-bars.
It seems that the error bar is tied to a label rather than the actual data, but i dont want do display the label. is there a way to either not declare a label an still have error bars, or just hide the label.

```
var barChartData = {
  labels: ["shouldNotBeDisplayed"],
  datasets: [{
    data: [
      56,
    ],
    errorBars: {
      shouldNotBeDisplayed: {plus: 1, minus: 1},
    }
  }]
};
```

you can try it out here and see the chart:
https://codepen.io/reckert/pen/rNWmdeK

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out `tick` labels by defining a `yAxes.ticks.callback` function as follows.

```
options: {
  ...
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        callback: () => undefined
     }
   }]
},
```

> For further details, please consult chapter [Creating Custom Tick Formats](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats) from the Chart.js documentation.